# Why are my list elements converted to tibbles?

Tags: r, data-structures

I'm starting with R and trying to organize some data into a nested list like this:

```
library(readr)    
dataframe1 <- read_csv2("sampleData.csv", col_names = FALSE)

# convert dataframe to a nested list
width <- ncol(sampleData)
nestedList <- list()
for(i in 1:width){
  nestedList[[i]] = list(name=dataframe1[1, i], attribute1 = dataframe1[2, i], attribute2 = dataframe1[3, i], attribute3 = dataframe1[4, i])
}
```

When I try accessing elements from the list, they are always displayed as tibbles, like this:

```
> nestedList[[1]]$name
# A tibble: 1 x 1
      X1
   <chr>
1 B06_01
```

So the lists really seem to be lists, but why are single elements automatically a tibble? (I understand that [tibble](https://github.com/hadley/tibble) is an enhanced dataframe class.) Why aren't they vectors? Also, I noticed that even numeric values end up as "chr" in the nested list.

Comment: Because data.frame1 was read in using `readr`'s `read_csv2` function. This function, by default, imports data of `tbl` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when subsetting tibble object it still keeps its attributes, try below example:

```
library(tibble)

as_tibble(mtcars)[1, 1]
# # A tibble: 1 x 1
#     mpg
#   <dbl>
# 1    21

mtcars[1, 1]
# [1] 21


attributes(as_tibble(mtcars)[1, 1])
# $names
# [1] "mpg"
# 
# $row.names
# [1] 1
# 
# $class
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

attributes(mtcars[1, 1])
# NULL
```

Comment: i see (although i cannot see where your example demonstrates that taking a single value out of a tibble still produces a subset-tibble)

Comment: @prinzminz `as_tibble(mtcars)` converts it to tibble object, then I am subsetting first row, first column, `as_tibble(mtcars)[1, 1]`. One row, one column is a single value.